# How do I vertically align text in a div?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am trying to find the most effective way to align text with a div. I have tried a few things and none seem to work.

```css
.testimonialText {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 309px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-style: italic;
  padding: 1em 0 1em 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="testimonialText">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Comment: There is an example at this url : [http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/](http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/) .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontal-and-vertical-inside-a-div-block/25799339#25799339

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 933, accepted):

#### The correct way to do this in modern browsers is to use Flexbox.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13515693/102937) for details.

See below for some older ways that work in older browsers.

---

**Vertical Centering in CSS**

http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Article summary:

For a CSS 2 browser, one can use `display:table`/`display:table-cell` to center content.

A sample is also available at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SVJaK/):

```css
div { border:1px solid green;}
```

```html
<div style="display: table; height: 400px; overflow: hidden;">
  <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
    <div>
      everything is vertically centered in modern IE8+ and others.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It is possible to merge hacks for old browsers (Internet Explorer 6/7) into styles with using `#` to hide styles from newer browsers:

```css
div { border:1px solid green;}
```

```html
<div style="display: table; height: 400px; #position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
  <div style=
    "#position: absolute; #top: 50%;display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
    <div style=" #position: relative; #top: -50%">
      everything is vertically centered
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is quite ludicrous that tables are frowned upon as some kind of old-fashioned hack only a newbie would use, and here we are using "display:table-cell" in a DIV as a far hackier workaround.

Comment: @Desty I thought the same thing until I started working on accessibility.  It wasn't until I saw how screen readers do their thing that I started to accept this 'new' way of thinking.

Comment: @MarcelWilson I would have thought screen readers would find it easier to reason about simple tables. I know there's the `aria-...` attributes that can help when using divs to simulate tables, but surely that's like spraying air freshener on a dog turd instead of removing it.

Answer (score 925):

You need to add the `line-height` attribute and that attribute must match the height of the `div`. In your case:

```css
.center {
  height: 309px;
  line-height: 309px; /* same as height! */
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  A single line.
</div>
```

In fact, you could probably remove the `height` attribute altogether.

This only works for **one line of text** though, so be careful.

Comment: I believe that's only valid if you have a single line of text in the div.

Comment: Absolutely, you'd have crazy line spacing in your text if it ran on more than 1 line.

Answer (score 686):

### Here's a great resource

From http://howtocenterincss.com/:

> Centering in CSS is a pain in the ass. There seems to be a gazillion ways to do it, depending on a variety of factors. This consolidates them and gives you the code you need for each situation.

### Using Flexbox

Inline with keeping this post up to date with the latest tech, here's a much easier way to center something using Flexbox. Flexbox isn't supported in *Internet Explorer 9 and lower*.

Here are some great resources:

- [A guide to Flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
- [Centering elements with Flexbox](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/22/centering-elements-with-flexbox/)
- [Internet Explorer 10 syntax for Flexbox](http://zomigi.com/blog/flexbox-syntax-for-ie-10/)
- [Support for Flexbox](http://caniuse.com/flexbox)

[JSFiddle with browser prefixes](http://jsfiddle.net/Sw3Jd/285/)

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* Column | row */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Some Text</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>A bit more text that goes on two lines</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Even more text that demonstrates how lines can span multiple lines</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

### Another solution

[This is from **zerosixthree** and lets you center anything with six lines of CSS](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)

This method isn't supported in *Internet Explorer 8 and lower*.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sw3Jd/310/)

```css
p {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>Some Text</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>A bit more text that goes on two lines</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>Even more text that demonstrates how lines can span multiple lines</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

### Previous answer

A simple and cross-browser approach, useful as links in the marked answer are slightly outdated.

> **How to vertically and horizontally center text in both an unordered list and a div without resorting to JavaScript or CSS line heights**. No matter how much text you have you won't have to apply any special classes to specific lists or divs (the code is the same for each). This works on all major browsers including Internet Explorer 9, Internet Explorer 8, Internet Explorer 7, Internet Explorer 6, Firefox, Chrome, [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29) and Safari. There are two special stylesheets (one for Internet Explorer 7 and another for Internet Explorer 6) to help them along due to their CSS limitations which modern browsers don't have.

#### [Andy Howard - How to vertically and horizontally center text in an unordered list or div](http://www.andy-howard.com/verticalAndHorizontalAlignment/index.html)

As I didn't care much for Internet Explorer 7/6 for the last project I worked on, I used a slightly stripped down version (i.e. removed the stuff that made it work in Internet Explorer 7 and 6). It might be useful for somebody else...

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sw3Jd/)

```css
.outerContainer {
  display: table;
  width: 100px;
  /* Width of parent */
  height: 100px;
  /* Height of parent */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.outerContainer .innerContainer {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="outerContainer">
      <div class="innerContainer">
        <div class="element">
          <p>
            <!-- Content -->
            Content
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div class="outerContainer">
      <div class="innerContainer">
        <div class="element">
          <p>
            <!-- Content -->
            Content
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the list answer. I really wanted something without `flex` cause that doesn't play nice with my auto text resizer. This worked!

Answer (score 222):

It is easy with `display: flex`. With the following method, the text in the `div` will be centered vertically:

```css
div {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* More style: */
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #888;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Your text here.
</div>
```

And if you want, horizontal:

```css
div {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* More style: */
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #888;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Your text here.
</div>
```

You must see the browser version you need; in old versions the code doesn’t work.

Answer (score 115):

I use the following to vertically center random elements easily:

#### HTML:

```html
<div style="height: 200px">
    <div id="mytext">This is vertically aligned text within a div</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```css
#mytext {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%; 
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

This centers the text in my `div` to the exact vertical middle of a 200px-high outer `div`. Note that you may need to use a browser prefix (like `-webkit-` in my case) to make this work for your browser.

This works not only for text, but also for other elements.

Answer (score 77):

Try this, add on the parent div:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

Answer (score 44):

You can do this by setting the display to 'table-cell' and applying a `vertical-align: middle;`:

```
    {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

This is however not supported by all versions of Internet Explorer according to this excerpt I copied from [http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp/%22w3%20schools%22) without permission.

**Note:** The values "inline-table", "table", "table-caption", "table-cell", "table-column", "table-column-group", "table-row", "table-row-group", and "inherit" are not supported by Internet Explorer 7 and earlier. Internet Explorer 8 requires a !DOCTYPE. Internet Explorer 9 supports the values.

The following table shows the allowed display values also from [http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp/%22w3schools%22).

[image]

Answer (score 42):

These days (we don't need Internet Explorer 6-8 any more) I would just use CSS `display: table` for this issue (or `display: flex`).

Table:

```css
.vcenter {
    display: table;
    background: #eee; /* optional */
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center; /* optional */
}

.vcenter > :first-child {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="vcenter">
  <p>This is my Text</p>
</div>
```

Flex:

```css
.vcenter {
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center; 
    height: 150px;
    justify-content: center; /* optional */
    background: #eee;  /* optional */
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="vcenter">
  <p>This is my text</p>
</div>
```

---

#### For older browsers:

This is (actually, was) my favorite solution for this issue (simple and very well browser supported):

```css
div {
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

.vcenter {
    background: #eee;  /* optional */
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

.vcenter:before {
    content: " ";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 0.001%; /* Just in case the text wrapps, you shouldn't notice it */
}

.vcenter > :first-child {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 99.999%;
}
```

```html
<div class="vcenter">
  <p>This is my text</p>
</div>
<div class="vcenter">
  <h4>This is my Text<br/>Text<br/>Text</h4>
</div>
<div class="vcenter">
  <div>
   <p>This is my</p>
   <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 28):

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) worked perfectly for me, centering multiple elements inside parent div horizontally & vertically.

Code below stacks all elements inside of parent-div in a column, centering the elements horizontally & vertically.
I used the child-div to keep the two Anchor elements on same line (row). Without child-div all three elements (Anchor, Anchor & Paragraph) are stacked inside parent-div's column on top of each other. Here only child-div is stacked inside parent-div column.

```css
.parent-div {
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
  <div class="child-div">
    <a class="footer-link" href="https://www.github.com/">GitHub</a>
    <a class="footer-link" href="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</a>
    <p class="footer-copywrite">© 2019 Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use display grid and place-items center:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid red;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Lorem, ipsum dolor.
</div>
```

Answer (score 15):

Very very simple solution, I used it in my projects many times which is:

**Source Code**

```
.welcome_box{
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: solid 1px #dadada;
}

<div class="welcome_box">Hello Friends</div>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Thanks to ask this question. Happy to share.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a solution that works best for a single line of text.

It can also work for multi-lined text with some tweaking if the number of lines is known.

```
.testimonialText {
    font-size: 1em; /* Set a font size */
}
.testimonialText:before { /* Add a pseudo element */
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 50%;
    margin-top: -0.5em; /* Half of the font size */
}
```

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ovccwrf/).

Answer (score 9):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      .container {
        height: 250px;
        background: #f8f8f8;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      p{
        font-size: 24px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can align center text vertically inside a div using Flexbox.

```
<div>
   <p class="testimonialText">This is the testimonial text.</p>
</div>

div {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

You can learn more about it at *[A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)*.

Answer (score 6):

Check this simple solution:

#### HTML

```
<div class="block-title"><h3>I'm a vertically centered element</h3></div>
```

#### CSS

```
.block-title {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 88px
}

.block-title h3 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: inherit
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xyv5F/3/)

Answer (score 6):

This is the cleanest solution I have found (Internet Explorer 9+) and adds a fix for the "off by .5 pixel" issue by using `transform-style` that other answers had omitted.

```
.parent-element {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Source: *[Vertical align anything with just 3 lines of CSS](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)*

Answer (score 6):

Using CSS grid did it for me:

```css
.outer {
    background-color: grey;
    width: 10rem;
    height: 10rem;
    display: grid;
    justify-items: center;
}

.inner {
    background-color: #FF8585;
    align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
    <div class='inner'>
       Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

HTML :

```
<div class="col-md-2 ml-2 align-middle">
    <label for="option2" id="time-label">Time</label>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.align-middle {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a simpler way to vertically align the content without resorting to table/table-cell:

http://jsfiddle.net/bBW5w/1/

In it I have added an invisible (width=0) div that assumes the entire height of the container.

It seems to work in Internet Explorer and Firefox (latest versions). I didn't check with other browsers

```
  <div class="t">
     <div>
         everything is vertically centered in modern IE8+ and others.
     </div>
      <div></div>
   </div>
```

And of course the CSS:

```
.t, .t > div:first-child
{
    border: 1px solid green;
}
.t
{
    height: 400px;
}
.t > div
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle
}
.t > div:last-child
{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution to an element of not knowing values:

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="center">
        whatever
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main {
    position: relative
}

.center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

According to Adam Tomat's answer there was prepared a *JSFiddle* [**example**](https://jsfiddle.net/romleon/epxbzgp4/) to align the text in **div**:

```
<div class="cells-block">    
    text<br/>in the block   
</div>
```

by using **display:flex** in CSS:

```
.cells-block {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    align-items: center;       /* Vertically   */
    justify-content: flex-end; /* Horisontally */
    text-align: right;         /* Addition: for text's lines */
}
```

with another [**example**](https://jsfiddle.net/romleon/vznkbvay/) and a few explanations in [a blog post](http://olgastattest.blogspot.com/2017/08/texts-alignment-inside-block.html).

Answer (score 4):

Margin auto on a grid-item.

Similarly to Flexbox, applying margin auto on a grid-item centers it on both axes:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
}
.element {
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```css
h1 {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.container {
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>Vertical align text</h1>
</div>
```

With this trick, you can align anything if you don't want to make it center add "left:0" to align left.

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

```
<div class="relative"><!--used as a container-->
    <!-- add content here to to make some height and width
    example:<img src="" alt=""> -->
    <div class="absolute">
        <div class="table">
            <div class="table-cell">
                Vertical contents goes here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .relative {
     position: relative;
 }
 .absolute {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 }
 .table {
     display: table;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     color: #fff;
 }
 .table-cell {
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using flex, be careful with differences in browsers' rendering.

This works well both for Chrome and Internet Explorer:

```css
.outer {
    display: flex;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #ffc;
}

.inner {
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #fcc;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer"><div class="inner">Active Tasks</div></div>
```

Compare with this one that works only with Chrome:

```css
.outer {
    display: flex;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #ffc;
}

.inner {
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #fcc;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner"><span style=" margin: auto;">Active Tasks</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another variation of the `div` in a `div` pattern using `calc()` in CSS.

```
<div style="height:300px; border:1px solid green;">
  Text in outer div.
  <div style="position:absolute; height:20px; top:calc(50% - 10px); border:1px solid red;)">
    Text in inner div.
  </div>
</div>
```

This works, because:

- `position:absolute` for precise placement of the `div` within a `div`
- we **know** the height of the inner `div` because we set it to `20px`.
- `calc(50% - 10px)` for **50% - half the height** for centering the inner `div`

Comment: The parent div would need position: relative

Answer (score 1):

This works fine:

#### HTML

```
<div class="information">
    <span>Some text</span>
    <mat-icon>info_outline</mat-icon>
</div>
```

#### Sass

```
.information {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px 0;
    span {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    mat-icon {
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
}
```

Without and with the image tag `<mat-icon>` (which is a font).

Answer (score 1):

You can use css `flexbox`.

```css
.testimonialText {
  height: 500px;
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #b4d2d2;
}
```

```html
<div class="testimonialText">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Comment: Pls mention that you need to specify `height`; otherwise won't work.

Answer (score 1):

This will center text vertically:

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-flex
}

.testimonialText {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="testimonialText">
    Hello World
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This snippet doesn't actually align the text in the center vertically.. fyi

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, there're obviously many ways to solve this.

But I have a `<div>` that's positioned absolutely, `height:100%` (actually, `top:0;bottom:0` and fixed width) and `display:table-cell` just didn't work to center text vertically.  My solution did require an inner span element, but I see many of the other solutions do also, so I might as well add it:

My container is a `.label` and I want the number vertically centered in it.  I did it by positioning absolutely at `top:50%` and setting `line-height:0`

```
<div class="label"><span>1.</span></div>
```

And the CSS is as follows:

```
.label {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:30px;
}

.label>span {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    line-height:0;
}
```

See it in action:  http://jsfiddle.net/jcward/7gMLx/

Comment: Nice because it's simplest solution. Downside is it works only for single line text, see fork of the example with longer text. http://jsfiddle.net/6sWfw/

Answer (score 0):

We can use display: flex concept to display text in center in input element type=checkbox

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.app-container {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contentpanel {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.lowerpanel {
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 4em;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 30%;
}


#hide {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-appearance: initial;
  width: 10px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #858585;
  background: #fff;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fff 0%, #969696 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 1px #adadad;
  font-size: 25px;
}

[for="hide"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #bee;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0.25em;
  display: block;
  width: max-content;
  margin: auto;
}

#hide:checked~.lowerpanel {
  width: 100%;
}

#hide:checked~.contentpanel {
  display: none;
}

#hide:checked:after {
  content: '>';
}

#hide:after {
  content: '<';
}
```

```html
<div class="app-container">
  <div class="contentpanel"></div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="hide">
  <div class="lowerpanel"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

There are [several tricks](http://www.css-jquery-design.com/2013/12/css-techniques-absolute-horizontal-and-vertical-centering-in-css/) to display content or an image in the center of a div. Some of the answers are really nice and I am fully agree with these too.

**Absolute Horizontal And Vertical Centering In CSS**

http://www.css-jquery-design.com/2013/12/css-techniques-absolute-horizontal-and-vertical-centering-in-css/

There are more than [10 techniques with examples](http://www.css-jquery-design.com/2013/12/css-techniques-absolute-horizontal-and-vertical-centering-in-css/). Now it's up to you which you prefer.

***No doubt, `display:table; display:table-Cell` is a better trick.***

Some good tricks are the following:

**Trick 1 - By using `display:table; display:table-cell`**

*HTML*

```
<div class="Center-Container is-Table">
  <div class="Table-Cell">
    <div class="Center-Block">
        CONTENT
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*CSS Code*

```
.Center-Container.is-Table { display: table; }
.is-Table .Table-Cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.is-Table .Center-Block {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**Trick 2 - By using `display:inline-block`**

*HTML*

```
<div class="Center-Container is-Inline">
  <div class="Center-Block">
     CONTENT
  </div>
</div>
```

*CSS code*

```
.Center-Container.is-Inline {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: auto;
}

.Center-Container.is-Inline:after,
.is-Inline .Center-Block {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.Center-Container.is-Inline:after {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -0.25em; /* To offset spacing. May vary by font */
}

.is-Inline .Center-Block {
  max-width: 99%; /* Prevents issues with long content causes the content block to be pushed to the top */
  /* max-width: calc(100% - 0.25em) /* Only for Internet&nbsp;Explorer 9+ */
}
```

**Trick 3 - By using `position:relative;position:absolute`**

```
<div style="position: relative; background: #ddd; border: 1px solid #ddd; height: 250px;">
  <div style="width: 50%; height: 60%; overflow: auto; margin: auto; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; background: #ccc; text-align: center;">
    <h4>ABSOLUTE CENTER, <br/>
WITHIN CONTAINER.</h4>
    <p>This box is absolutely centered, horizontally and vertically, within its container</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you need to use with the `min-height` property you must add this CSS on:

```
.outerContainer .innerContainer {
    height: 0;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to embed a table element.

```html
<div>
  <table style='width:200px; height:100px;'>
    <td style='vertical-align:middle;'>
      copenhagen
    </td>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Tables are only for dealing with tabular data. They should never be used to fix layout problems.

Comment: Nice thing about tables though, is they are always consistent - CSS is interpreted so many different ways and putting nested DIVs in just to get something simple done adds extra HTML (and confusion). CSS is still grossly flawed

Comment: Yes, Unfortunately this **IS STILL** the only reliable way to vertically align (unknown) text in a block. Why do the CSS gods hate valign so much ? (ALL browser CAN do it consistently - but only in table cells)

Answer (score -2):

CSS:

```
.vertical {
   display: table-caption;
}
```

Add this class to the element that contains the things you want to align vertically